# overloaded panel, possible load sharing

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a 100 amp panel, during a remodel the gas appliances were replaced with electric and now the load calcs put it at about 105 amps. I've heard about way to power 2 loads or appliances with 1 breaker. The application I heard about was for an electric car charger being added to a panel that didn't have enough capacity. This device allows only one appliance to draw power at a time. I'm hoping to have the clothes dryer and a small oven connected in this manner. Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: What is your basis for saying the panel is oversubscribed?  Lots of 100A houses have electric kitchen and laundry.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel and directory?  Also, how many square feet is your house, how many kitchen receptacle branch circuits do you have, and are your hot water heater, heating/cooling, and range electric or gas? (You are talking about an *electric* dryer, for that matter, right?)

Comment: Voting to close. OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really understand how to determine the actual LOAD on the panel? You don't just add up the values of the breaker handles. I say that because your question about putting two loads on one breaker seems to imply that this will make a difference. It will not (and by the way you cannot legally put two wires on the terminals of most breakers).

Determining the loading on a service is a complex issue involving knowing the ACTUAL wattage of major appliances, legal limits to loads on outlet circuits, and what's called a "diversity factor" that is a method of acknowledging that not all circuits will be on and drawing full power at the same time. If you are concerned, study up on how this is done.

Comment: That question is what I'm trying to fish out of OP.  I wouldn't presume because on a 100A sized panel it could go either way.